# Approaching a 2nd order, non-linear ODE with variable coefficients: $f''(x) + (1-B^2x^2)f(x) - f(x)^3 = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, boundary-value-problem, hypergeometric-function, initial-value-problems

Given a differential equation:

$$f''(x) + (1-B^2x^2)f(x) - f(x)^3 = 0$$

subject to the boundary conditions

$$f(x=0) =0
\qquad f(x\to\infty) = \gamma_A$$
where $\gamma_A$ is some constant between 0 and 1.

As it stands, this is a non-linear, 2nd order ODE. My undergraduate experience had shockingly little exposure to these type of equations, even if I was to omit the non-linear term.

Dropping the final $f(x)^3$ term I believe leads to some kind of Whittaker(?) type equation with some hypergeometric functions, but I have not encountered these before. I am not sure if there even exists an obvious way to solve this analytically, and I am not even certain if I can solve this numerically with the boundary condition tending to infinity - the non-constant $x^2f(x)^2$ makes incorporating this difficult. How would one begin to approach a problem like this? I would be very interested to hear the approach that one might take to even to begin solving.

My instinct suggests that this should appear to be a tanh-like solution, beginning at 0 and having an asymptote towards $\gamma_A$ as $x$ is increased. In the full, non-linear equation, taking the case $B=0$ and $\gamma_A =1 $ in fact leads to a tanh solution, but it is not clear what the analytic solution is when $\gamma_A \neq 1 $, although this is easier to solve numerically for. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti thank you for your comment. I am unsure if I follow your reasoning, particularly with the last point. If we take $\gamma_A =1$, then $f(x\to\infty) = 1$, and hence $f''(x) \sim 0$ as $x\to\infty$. Does this not then imply that $f(x) \sim C*x$ which is a similar contradiction? Moreover, for your final point regarding $B=0$ and $0 < \gamma_A < 1$, it is possible to find numerical solutions to this, despite not having a clear analytic solution?

Comment: I see; certainly seems like an analytic solution for both of these is impossible. I think a numerical solution is my only hope... I am currently trying to mess around with the boundaries and take the idea that instead of going to $\infty$, I take the boundary at some finite $L$, which might render these solutions possible. Thank you for your insight @RicardoCavalcanti